# Porting 2d tile based iPhone game to Android.

Tags: java, android, game-engine

Are there any good 2d tile based game engines for android I should look into before just jumping right into canvas painting for this game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) and [LibGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) are the most common game engines used for Android. They both have good tileset support, and offer a lot of help for making games, including compatibility with the Box2D physics engine.